# Moving element with Javascript with correct cursor positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I move elements with the mouse whilst positioning them correct with the cursor?

Like in this fiddle the div always jumps to its 0x0 position:

```
var isMouseDown = false;

$('div')
    .mousedown(function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
  })
  .mousemove(function(event) {
    if(isMouseDown) {
        $(this).css({
        'top': event.pageY, // Offset missing
        'left': event.pageX
      });
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc844Lea/5/

Answer (score 1):

Subtract half of the `width` of the element to `left` and half of the `height` of the element to `top`.

```
var isMouseDown = false;
$('div').mousedown(function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
}).mousemove(function(event) {
    var heightWidth = this.getBoundingClientRect().height/2;
    if(isMouseDown) {
      $(this).css({'top': event.pageY - heightWidth,'left': event.pageX - heightWidth });
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc844Lea/7/)